# Is the ordering of subviews of NSView guaranteed?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, subview

When using `[[NSView subviews] objectAtIndex:]`, can we guarantee that this will pick the same view each time?

**Background:** I am using an `IKScannerDeviceView` and want to hide the file format selection. I do this with the following code:

```
NSView *parameterView = [[[[_scannerView subviews][0] subviews][1] subviews][0] subviews][0];

NSView *v1 = [parameterView subviews][37];
[v3 setHidden:YES];
NSView *v2 = [parameterView subviews][38];
[v4 setHidden:YES];
```

In testing, this always hides the correct views, but can I guarantee that this will always be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build the hierarchy yourself and do it in the same way each time the order is deterministic.

Obviously the order of an unknown hierarchy of views that you don't control is not guaranteed. In the case of an `IKScannerDeviceView` the view hierarchy should be considered private.